# Probability of drawing a good ticket

Tags: probability

The problem:
A group of 16 people took the statistics exam. There are 32 tickets on the syllabus, five of which the students think are good tickets. Which one should take turns entering the classroom to be the most likely to draw a good ticket?

Directions.
Explicitly calculating the probability of drawing a good ticket for the first n < 16 through the full probability formula will not count as a solution to the problem.Try, for example, using the coding method by representing the ticket pullout sequence as a binary vector of size 32.

My attempt:
Obviously the probability of the first student getting a "good" ticket is 5/32=0.16

If the first student got a "good" ticket then the chances of the second student are 4/31=0.13, so lower than the first student.

However if the first student didn't get a "good" ticket, the chances of the second student are 5/31=0.16.

Is my reasoning correct in solving this problem?

Comment: What you are saying is correct but it does not answer the plain question: "what is the probability that the second student gets a good ticket?" So actually you did not solve the problem yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

There are $32$ tickets and all have *equal* probability to become the ticket drawn by for instance the student that enters in as number $12$.

Among those tickets are $5$ good tickets.

By equiprobable outcomes:

$$\text{probability }=\text{ number of favorable outcomes divided by number of possible outcomes}$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand it.

Comment: That is nice to hear. You are welcome.